# Is there a FLOSS app freeze app for Android 4.0?

Tags: android, open-source

The application should be able to prevent the app from loading at boot and managing this status as frozen or not (e.g. in a list). That the application requires root privileges shouldn't be a problem.

Examples of non-FLOSS apps are AppFreezer and RootAppDelete.

Where I tried searching:

- Searching Google PlayStore for FLOSS apps is useless because Google providing a way to uninstall the pre-installed advertisement wouldn't make sense.
- F-Droid doesn't return any results for the search query "freeze".
- Android forums are very hard to read due to the lack of structuring a Q&A provides (I searched 20 posts in 4 forums for any helpful content and gave up).

Comment: @Timmy "[App freeze](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/disable-app/info)" is quite a standing term in the Android community ;) // Karl: Unfortunately, there indeed seems to be no FLOSS tool for that. [My related app-listing](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_organize#group_456) has just pointers to Play and Aptoide here (nothing found on F-Droid, neither for "freeze" nor for "disable" or "remove").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tried it myself, but **[Disable Manager](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.nagopy.android.disablemanager2)** is available at F-Droid – and thus FOSS (nothing to do with tooth floss ;)

> Assists in the disabling of pre-installed apps. You can show lists of apps installed apps and can disable/enable them.

Looking for alternatives, if nothing shows up for "freeze" it might be because the official term is "disable". Apart from that, a few related apps are in my listing [Remove pre-installed Apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_organize#group_456).